# Cut a CSS transition short?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions

I'm applying a CSS transition to an element.

```
   target.style.transition = "color 10000ms ease";
   target.style.color = "red";
```

Under certain circumstances, I want the end state of this transition to be reached immediately, without waiting for the transition to finish.

If I try

```
   target.style.transition = "color 0ms";
   target.style.color = "red";
```

the current transition just continues.

Doing

```
   target.style.transition = "color 0ms";
   target.style.color = "blue";
```

sets it to 'blue' immediately, while

```
   target.style.transition = "color 0ms";
   target.style.color = "blue";
   target.style.color = "red";
```

results in a continuation of the transition. (tried in both Chrome and FF)

Is there a way to stop the transition?

Comment: I expect they didn't think of this use-case. If possible, you could set it to (e.g.) `#FE0000` then use `setTimeout(function(){/*set to proper red here*/},0)` (same applies to several other properties you might be animating). Or you could animate it manually using `setInterval` or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the transition and reach the end state immediately, use

```
target.style.transition = "none";
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gqtrs/1/).

Comment: +1 This tested fine in all browsers. Here's a similar [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/XDF6j/5/) using the same approach.