# How to make transition duration to be the same for all values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

We have two similar width transitions, that are interrupted in the middle and their final transition values are changed.
The only difference between them is that green box final width is exactly the same as it's starting width and orange box final width is different from it's starting width.

This causes green box transition to be faster, as if it's just "undoing" the initial transition.

[image: animation]

**[Link to a full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Omnivoree/za0g87p2/8/)**

*html:*

```
<div id="reference"></div>
<div id="boxA" ></div>
<div id="boxB" ></div>
```

*css:*

```
#reference {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.5);
}

#boxA {
  background-color: rgba(166, 255, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#boxB {
  background-color: rgba(255, 136, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

*javascript:*

```
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

document.getElementById("boxA").style.width = "100px";
document.getElementById("boxB").style.width = "100px";

(async () => {
await sleep(1000)

document.getElementById("boxA").style.width = "200px";
document.getElementById("boxB").style.width = "200px";

await sleep(500)

document.getElementById("boxA").style.width = "100px";
document.getElementById("boxB").style.width = "101px";

})()
```

- What is the simplest way to make transition duration the same for all values, when destination value is changed, before the initial transition finished?
- Is the starting value the only special case?
- Where to find documentation for this weird behaviour?

Comment: The transition speed (1s) is the same for both `boxA` and `boxB`. Since `boxB` has a shorter distance to travel for the same elapsed time, it needs to move slower than `boxA`

Comment: @dillon both boxes expand to the same width and the shrinking takes 0.5 for a green box and 1s for an orange box

Comment: Hmm yeah this is really weird behavior but it seems like you have multiple transitions happening on the width at the same time since you're not waiting for it to complete.. Maybe this will be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16376109/cut-a-css-transition-short ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec is here: I'd check §3.4.4
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#starting

> Otherwise, implementations must cancel the running transition and start a new transition whose:
>
> ...
>
> - reversing-adjusted start value is the same as the start value, and

So if you return to the original value, then it's the same transition, but going to a new value it starts a new transition from the current value.

So one way to bypass this could be by passing in an intermediary value, just to trigger a new transition:

```
// go to any value (that is not the current value or the original value)
document.getElementById("boxA").style.width = "999px"; 

// Trigger reflow  (See @Kaiido's comment below)
 document.body.offsetWidth;

// and then immediately go back to the original value
document.getElementById("boxA").style.width = "100px";
```

Now both boxes will have two transitions that will have the same duration, but one will end at 100px, and the other at 101px.

---

Also I think the rationale explained is relevant:  [§3.1 Faster reversing of interrupted transitions](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#reversing)

Comment: You need to trigger a reflow after you did set the fake value (e.g `document.getElementById("boxA").style.width = "999px"; document.body.offsetWidth; document.getElementById("boxA").style.width = "100px";` see [your current code](https://jsfiddle.net/4pemfgjy/), vs [fixed one](https://jsfiddle.net/4pemfgjy/1)

Comment: @Kaiido huh, right you are. I swear I tried it out in the jsfiddle above and thought it was working, but reconfirming now I see you are right.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a perfect answer, as I can not tell you what value would be right for every different element, but it works :

```js
box1 = document.getElementById("boxA");
box2 = document.getElementById("boxB");

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

box1.style.width = "100px";
box2.style.width = "100px";

(async() => {
  await sleep(1000)

  box1.style.width = "200px";
  box2.style.width = "200px";

  await sleep(500)

  box1.style.width = "100px";
  box2.style.transitionDuration = "0.5s";
  box2.style.width = "101px";

})()
```

```css
#reference {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 204, 255, 0.5);
}

#boxA {
  background-color: rgba(166, 255, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

#boxB {
  background-color: rgba(255, 136, 0, 0.5);
  height: 100px;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="reference"></div>
<div id="boxA"></div>
<div id="boxB"></div>
```

**Explanation :** Both `box` elements increase to `200px`, and after that, the first box goes back to `100px`, whereas, the second `box` element reduces just by `99px`. As it has to cover lesser distance than the first box, its `transition duration` has to be reduced as well.